# C Adding value to array? `array + value`

Tags: c, arrays

I was looking through some code, and I stumbled upon this line of code. (With other lines of code to provide context)

```
void write32le(int in, unsigned char * buf) {
    buf[0]=in&0xff;
    buf[1]=(in>>8)&0xff;
    buf[2]=(in>>16)&0xff;
    buf[3]=(in>>24)&0xff;
}
```

.......

```
unsigned char wavhead[44] = {
    0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  0x57, 0x41, 0x56, 0x45, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x74, 0x20,
    0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61,  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };
```

.......

```
write32le(outsizetotal,wavhead+4);
```

The last two lines pieces of code are in the same function if that makes a difference, and the question I have is in the last line. 
"wavhead+4", what exactly is it doing? Appending the number 4 to 'wavhead'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it passes the address of (the pointer to) the 5th element of the array (which has index 4, as indexes starts from zero).

You need to learn pointers and arrays. In C you can't add or remove elements from the array

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are a continuous block of memory accessed by an address (the location of element 0) and an offset.

`wavehead+4` evaluates to the address of the 5th element in the array. The method it's passed into (`write32le`) will see the 5th element of the array as the 1st element.

```
// If we take an array
int myArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
// And pass it into a method as
myMethod(myArr+2);
// the method will see (assuming it knows the length of the array which it won't in c)
{ 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `write32le()` is to take a word that you wish to re-write as its first argument, and an index into to an array of `unsigned int` in the form of of a pointer.  `wavhead[index]` is that kind of pointer.

If you wanted to replace the first 4 bytes of `wavhead` with the word `0xDEADBEEF`, you would do this:

```
int main()
{
    int in=0xDEADBEEF;
    printf("Before write32le:\n ");
    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%hhx ", wavhead[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    write32le(in, wavhead);
    printf("After write32le:\n ");
    for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%hhx ", wavhead[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before write32le:
 0x52 0x49 0x46 0x46
After write32le:
 0xef 0xbe 0xad 0xde
```

Answer (score 0):

In majority of contexts (with only a few exceptions) an object of type "array" is implicitly converted to a value of type "pointer". The pointer points to the first element of the array. E.g. in such contexts plain `wavhead` is implicitly interpreted as `&wavhead[0]`.

In your case `wavhead` is used as an operand of binary `+` operator. Binary `+` is not an exception. So, `wavhead` decays to `&wavhead[0]` and your call is interpreted as

```
write32le(outsizetotal, &wavhead[0] + 4);
```

which means that what you really have here is "pointer + value", not "array + value".

The second argument results in a pointer to `wavhead[4]`. You could also rewrite it as

```
write32le(outsizetotal, &wavhead[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case, the name of the array wavhead[] is equal to a pointer of "unsigned char *", adding 4 to this pointer is just moving the pointer by 4 steps and the step is sizeof (unsigned char), which is 1. So wavhead+4 = the address of pointer wavhead + 4, and it points to wavhead[4] after the addition.